# how to use popup inside which leads to another page in flutter?

Tags: flutter

i would like to use a pop up which leads to a defined page. i saw in my researches that in a popup we used to define the widgets inside a dialog, i want to indicate inside a showdialog (eventually this method) the link to another page : 
here is what i did :

```
       showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) =>  MMPATASubcriptionDetailPage(
                       product: product,
                      viewModel: widget.viewModel,
                    )
                    );
```

the  MMPATASubcriptionDetailPage page is the page that i want to open when the popup is shown

Comment: Why would you want to show the dialog and not just open the new page, if that is all the dialog does?

Comment: in this case i would like to open the page with the same animation that popup

Comment: I don't think this is the way to do that. For animating routes you might want to check out this to get you started: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation